# You do not have permission to view this directory or page. error after uploading angular 6 project on Azure

Tags: angular, azure

I want to upload my angular 6 project on the azure but i am getting this error
"You don't have the permission to view this directory or page".
I gave a lot of my time to it and i done everything that i found on google about solving this problem. i also read the angular 6 documentation and followed the steps but still getting the same issue.

[This is the Screen Shot of my Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1gOw.png)

Can anyone help me? If so, then i will be very thankful to him.

Comment: have you restricted the webapp to IP ranges that you aren't in?

Comment: I don't know becoz i m completely new on cloud but i have uploaded the screenshot of my error in the question. you can check and plz tell me what is going on?

Comment: On the web app under settings there is a item called networking. Click that, then click Ip Restrictions if there is none there everything can access the web app and it’s a different problem

Comment: There is nothing in the ip restriction